# How to print foreignkey Model relation?

Tags: django

If in My model, Moneybook have a many moneylogs.

so, I design a model

Moneybook/models.py

```
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="행복한 여행!")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")
    companion = models.ManyToManyField(
        user_models.User, related_name="companion", blank=True)
    country = CountryField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=NOW)
```

Moneylog/models.py

```
moneybook = models.ForeignKey(
    moneybook_models.Moneybook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="moneybooks")
payer = models.ForeignKey(
    user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="payer")
dutch_payer = models.ManyToManyField(
    user_models.User, related_name="dutch_payer")
price = models.IntegerField()
category = models.CharField(max_length=10)
memo = models.TextField()
```

If i want to load all the moneylogs in the each belonging moneybook. how can i load it?

I guess...

```
def moneybook_detail(request, pk):
    moneylogs=moneylog.filter(moneylog.moneybook.id=request.moneybook.id)
    return render(request, "moneybooks/detail.html")
```

but error occured.

```
moneylogs = moneylog.filter(request.moneybook.id=request.moneybook.id)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either query the Moneylog table with the following query by using the double underscore `__` to filter based on referenced object fields.

```
moneylogs = MoneyLog.filter(moneybook__id=<<<MoneyBookID_GOES_HERE>>>)
```

---

Or by using the internal `ReverseManyToOneManager` in Django

just by using

```
moneybook = MoneyBook.objects.get(pk=<<<<MoneyBookID_GOES_HERE>>>>)
moneylogs = moneybook.moneylog_set.all() # all() to get all money logs
# You can do filter(...) on it too to filter the moneylogs too.
```

this will return all money logs related to the money book.

Comment: Thanks for reply! although, I import my Moneybook models, but it occur error : 
module 'moneybooks.models' has no attribute 'moneylog_set'

Comment: Try using `dir(moneybook)` to see the set of attributes moneybook object has, just look for anything with `_set` postfix.

Comment: wow it helps me. but my model has no _set postfix.. like,
from moneybooks import models as moneybook_models,
dir(moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']

Comment: use it like this `dir(moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(pk=<<<ID>>>))`, it should return `moneylog_set` since there is a `moneybook` **ForiegnKey** field, on the **Moneylog** model.

Comment: My moneybook model has 

moneybook = models.ForeignKey(
        moneybook_models.Moneybook, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="moneybooks")

but 

>>> moneybook=moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(id=1)
>>> moneylog=moneybook.moneylog_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Moneybook' object has no attribute 'moneylog_set'

I don't know what happening...

Comment: OMG I found it. because of the related_name, it doesn't work... i don't know what mechanism... but after I erase it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have to use double underscore `__` to reference foreign key columns in filters:

```
def moneybook_detail(request, pk):
    moneylogs=moneylog.filter(moneybook__id=request.moneybook.id)
    return render(request, "moneybooks/detail.html")
```